# JPA Many-to-One Mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am beginner in Hibernate JPA.

I used two (Tables)classes  `ClubForm & CoreClub.`

i need to join the table `CoreClub form ClubForm.`

I have the field `idCoreClub` in `ClubForm` &  `idCoreClub`  is primery key in `CoreClub`.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idCoreClub", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private CoreClub coreClub;
```

I used the above code to make the join, but i face the error,

```
[PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=CLUBFORM0_.IDCORECLUB, DRIVER=4.9.78]
```

How to map the Non Primery Key into another table's Primery key.

Please help me .

If possible please share the some basic tutorial links for Hibernate JPA.

Thanks in Advance,

K.Ramkumar.

Comment: Show us the code of your two entities, the DDL of the two tables, and the SQL query that Hibernate executes and which causes this exception. But it simply looks like you don't have any column named IDCORECLUB in the CLUBFORM table

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure,but try with this

```
@JoinColumn(name="id_core_club", insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer. Please find it below,

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_CORE_CLUB", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private CoreClub coreClub;
```